# How to adjucate the interaction between Blue Velvet location and Mass Manipulation

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

Blue Velvet location card reads:

> To Withdraw from here, you must Spend 2 blood

The rulebook is fairly explicit in saying you can't willingly send yourself into Frenzy, so we always play that you can't withdraw if you have 2 or less blood.

However, Mass Manipulation says:

> During the Withdraw Step at this Location, each Rival must either Withdraw or let you Steal 2 blood from them to Stay.

This presents players with sort of a paradox. If they have 2 blood, they can't let the Ventrue Steal 2 blood for them to Stay, so they have to retreat. But if they retreat they must Spend 2 blood, so they can't retreat either.

What we've been playing with is: in this scenario, the player is forced to Retreat by Blue Velvet, Spends 2 blood and Frenzies. Should that be the case? In this scenario, does the Ventrue player get 1 Influence Point for making that player Frenzy?